Program that reads 2 numbers and then divides them. Assembly Intel 8080
I need a program, that reads two numbers from the user (input). First number (x) must be in range 0 - 65535. Second one (y) needs to be in range 0-255. Then the program must divide those numbers z = x/y. It must check whether the input numbers are in the range (first 0-65535, second 0-255).
I am now at the moment when I want to read input from the user, but after showing the display message the program only accepts 1 character and I cannot input my first number for example 345, into it. I need to input those numbers with RST 2 - it reads a character from the keyboard (or if it is not possible, and you have better idea, input by other options). Also if you can, you can explain why did you do X operation instead of Y. Because I just started learning assembly and I'm not good at it, as you can see below :D.
Below is my code:
     ORG 800H 
JMP MAIN 
MSG_PRINT  
     LXI H,US_INP1  
     CALL DISPLAY  
DISPLAY  
     MOV A,M  
     CPI '$'  
     JZ DISPLAY_END  
     CALL DISPLAY_CHAR  
     INX H  
     JMP DISPLAY  
DISPLAY_END  
     RET  
DISPLAY_CHAR  
     RST 1  
     RET  
INPUT_NUMBER  
     RST 2  
     RET  
VALID_FIRST  
     MOV A,D  
     CPI 255  
     JC VALID_16BIT  
     JMP ERROR  
VALID_16BIT  
     RET  
VALID_SECOND  
     MOV A,B  
     CPI 255  
     JC VALID_8BIT  
     JMP ERROR  
VALID_8BIT  
     RET  
ERROR  
     LXI H,US_INPE  
     CALL DISPLAY  
     JMP MAIN  
SUCCESS  
     LXI H,US_INPOK  
     CALL DISPLAY  
     RET  
MAIN  
     LXI H,US_INP1  
     CALL DISPLAY  
     CALL INPUT_NUMBER  
     CALL VALID_FIRST  
     CALL SUCCESS  
     LXI H,US_INP2  
     CALL DISPLAY  
     CALL INPUT_NUMBER  
     CALL VALID_SECOND  
     CALL SUCCESS  
     HLT  
US_INP1      DB 'Input number (0-65535): $'  
US_INP2      DB 'Input number (0-255): $'      
US_INPE      DB 'Wrong number.$' 
US_INPOK     DB 'Correct number.$' 


Apparently this code runs in an environment where rst 2 reads and ASCII character.  The OP commented this in the staging-ground version of the post (https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79145811#comment139560188_79145811) without bothering to [edit] their question with any info about what environment that is or what registers system-calls modify or not.

The usual algorithm for multi-digit input is total = total*10 + digit, where digit is the ascii code minus '0' to get a 0..9 integer. e.g. for x86 NASM Assembly convert input to integer?
